# 3-terminal adjustable voltage regulator: elegant way for Vout=0 when Vin<(setpoint + dropout)?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, lm317

As I just discovered, when a 3-terminal adjustable voltage regulator (LM317, LD1086) is operating with Vin less than setpoint + dropout, its output is unregulated Vin - dropout.  I want it to output nothing, zero volts.

It occurs to me there might be a solution using an external zener and a PNP transistor that turns on when there is a greater than 0.6V difference between Vin and the zener setpoint, but then I would need a separate voltage divider to determine essentially the same setpoint, with two potentiometers in the case of an adjustable power supply.

Any more elegant solutions out there?  Perhaps there is a more-than-3-terminal device I should be using instead?

Comment: What is your desire Vout?  What is your worst case Vin?  What kind of circuitry do you have as the load?

Comment: Vin is a photovoltaic panel: 0V to 22V.  Output primarily drives a 12V nominal relay that remains engaged with as little as 2V.

Comment: Do you want the output to be a *low-impedance* zero volts in the case you mentioned? (Crow-barred to ground?) Or can it be a *high-impedance* and therefore floating output (which you can tie to ground with a resistor if you want?) Saying "nothing" doesn't seem to specify, to me. Also, I think you may need to realize that if there's only this one source, there will be a minimum voltage below which there isn't enough headroom to do much and you'll lose management, anyway.

Comment: High impedence is just fine.  The relay is driven by an N-enhancement MOSFET with a bleed-to-ground resistor.

Comment: It seems as though you need a voltage regulator with an *enable* pin, plus a brown-out circuit. Is that about it?

Comment: Sounds about right.  Any suggestions?

Comment: LP2952 has an error output for low output voltage and a shutdown input.  There may be others.

Comment: How accurate do you want the brown-out detector, do you want hysteresis, and is it okay if the brown-out detector only works down to perhaps 0.8 volts?

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2015/07/23/how-to-control-turn-on-off-thresholds-in-voltage-regulators-using-a-logic-level-uvlo But I have a simpler circuit I've posted before for this purpose (just didn't post it for this usage. If you decide to go with ENABLE, I'll bother posting something.)

Comment: Ah, yes.  The ULVO circuit #2 was about what I was envisioning, though I now realize I would have to use an external switch (MOSFET, bipolar) on the 3-terminal device; the adj third terminal pin is no help at all.  Better to use a more complicated device such as that LP2952.

Comment: I couldn't find a UVLO pin on an LDO linear regulator, but I did find both an enable pin and an error-condition pin on the 5-terminal Micrel MIC29300.  At this point my strategy is to charge a capacitor on the error pin, invert the signal with a transistor, and feed the result to the enable pin.  With a long enough RC time constant, I can prevent frequent start-ups.

Answer (score 1):

> Any more elegant solutions out there?

Sure there are. Just look for a regulator with a pin called UVLO. It stands for under voltage lock out and has internally a comparator that switches off the regulator's pass transistor when the input voltage is too low as set by a resistive potential divider applied externally to that pin.